# Capturing click event no redirect to app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to capture notification click event without redirecting to app it should stay on notification tray after clicking. App state could be foreground or background. Just like music app do in next, play and pause event.

Used Cordova Plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may have to tweak the plugin a bit. 
To keep the notification in place, I assume you've already set ongoing : true while you're scheduling it ?

If you're looking at the Android platform, you could try something like:

1) Install the plugin to a new folder or temporary project and take a look at "ClickActivity.java"

1.a) Remove the existing version of the plugin from your project

2) Modify the code to suppress or  tweak the call as you need it:

```html
public class ClickActivity extends de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity {

    /**
     * Called when local notification was clicked by the user.
     *
     * @param notification
     *      Wrapper around the local notification
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(Notification notification) {
  
  
        LocalNotification.fireEvent("click", notification);

        super.onClick(notification);

        if (notification.getOptions().isOngoing())
            return;

        String event = notification.isRepeating() ? "clear" : "cancel";
        LocalNotification.fireEvent(event, notification);
    }
```

3)Reinstall the version of the plugin from your custom directory

```
cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification --searchpath your-custom-path
```

For what I needed, I just suppressed the original calls - tacky, I know, but all I needed was a notification. Like you said, I didn't want it pulling the app to the foreground.

Will that do what you need ?